# Django Tutorial - ImproperlyConfigured exception (pytz isn't installed)

Tags: python, django, pytz

I'm currently working through the official Django tutorial using version 1.6.1 and version 2.7.5 of python on OSX. I'm working on part 2, which is the admin interface. When I attempt to go to /admin/polls/poll/, I get the following error report:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/polls/poll/
This query requires pytz, but it isn't installed.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/polls/poll/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
This query requires pytz, but it isn't installed.
Exception Location: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in datetime_trunc_sql, line 196
Python Executable:  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

I attempted to install pytz by installing pip (which required installing setuptools) but this made no difference. Also, I am going through this tutorial for a second time, and I know I didn't run into this problem a month ago. Could updating to Mavericks have caused some problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After continuing to search for django and pytz, I found the 1.6 Django release notes, which mention that you must now install pytz to work with Sqlite3 if USE_TZ=True in your settings.py.

I don't know what effect USE_TZ has on your application, but setting that value to False allows me to proceed in the tutorial. I would hope that the Django tutorial is updated to reflect this change.

Comment: USE_TZ=True makes the dates and times timezone aware. This is usually required if users from different timezones need to use your app. More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: If the default for USE_TZ is true (and probably required for most apps), should pytz be included with Django?

BTW I finally got pytz working, and was able to re-enable USE_TZ. On Mac, I did:

"sudo easy_install pip" then
"sudo pip install pytz"

and this time, it seemed to work fine. I was manually installing setuptools and pip from .py scripts on their respective sites, and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: It was running fine for me until I upgraded to from Django 1.4 to 1.8, does it means USE_TZ wasn't previously enabled and now it is enabled by default? I don't remember enabling it or having any problems with it before.

Answer (score 17):

I was also getting the same error.
I installed  pytz

```
$ pip install pytz
```

and then i restarted the server. The exception is no more now.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is very simple..

```
pip install pytz
```

and then stop and restart your server

Answer (score 2):

I had same error, then I installed pytz with `pip install pytz` and again had same error until I restarted WSGI instance. (eg.  touching wsig.py (`touch wsgi.py`) or restarting apache (`apache2ctl restart`)